# How to display shipping and billing forms at same time on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento-2.0, magento2.2.2

So I need for my shipping and billing form on checkout to display both at the same time. Right now only the shipping address is being shown and the billing address has a checkmark where it says "my billing is the same as shipping" I need to be able to uncheck that box and have both shipping and billing open and displayed when a customer visits checkout.

I tried this and it has a bunch of bugs...

[image]